# "Hamakom" after shiv'a

Tags: halacha, minhag, blessing, mourning-aveilus, social-convention

In my experience, for the most part, "‏המקום ינחם אתכם בתוך שאר אבלי ציון וירושלים" is said to a mourner specifically during *shiv'a*. However, I've heard some people say it after *shiv'a*, particularly the first time they speak to the mourner as a mourner. (Because I'm mostly unacquainted with that practice, I say something less formulaic if speaking to a mourner for the first time, e.g. "*Hashem* should give you *nechama*".) So my question is twofold:

1. Does *halacha* (or the *minhag* of any communities) say anything about this? Specifically, is "*Hamakom…*" restricted to *shiv'a*? (Or do any halachic sources say explicitly that it's not?)
2. (Especially if the answer to #1 is that halachic sources say nothing…) What's the convention? (This will depend on location, of course.)

Comment: Is this an answer? https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%94_%D7%91

Comment: @DoubleAA, not alone, but maybe in context or with _nos'e kelim_.

Comment: I think "KeDarko" in this case would be using your formulation, and hence permitted until 30. (I don't really know of any reason that you ought to use that formulation. It's just not easy to think of a new personal one every time.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

גשר החיים ([vol. 1 20:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31174&st=&pgnum=182)) writes:

(*translation mine*)

> אם לא נחמו תוך ז׳ ופגע בו תוך ל׳ — מביע לו ג״כ ברכת
>    תנחומין הנהוגה. ואחר ל׳ אומר לו רק ״תתנחם״. ועל אביו ואמו מנחמו כל
>    י״ב תרש (טוש״ע שם).‏
>
> If he did not console him within the seven [days of mourning] and met him during *shloshim*, he should also also express the customary blessing of consolation. After *shloshim* he should only say "[May you] be consoled". [If one is mourning] for his father or mother,he should console him throughout the [first] twelve months.

(*credit: [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa)*)