# Why does the shiva expression begn with term המקום?

Tags: mourning-aveilus, sitting-shiva

Prior to leaving the shiva house, visitors say to the mourners:

> המקום ינחם אתכם...

Meaning (literally) "The place should comfort you..."

WHat is the meaning of referring to God as "the place" when God has no specific place. Why is this term chosen for shiva as opposed to using one of God's names such as אדוני?

Comment: WHat is the meaning of referring to God as "the place" when God has no specific place. Is a totally different question from Why is this term chosen for shiva as opposed to using one of God's names such as אדוני. Consider asking them separately.

Comment: You could kill two birds with one stone. Stop this from being a dupe, and limit it to one question, by just asking about the name hamakom. (assuming that isn't also a dupe).

Comment: It's not unique to shiva http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68806/759 (probably)